# Git push to TFS stop on 100 percent

Tags: git, tfs, png, push, freeze

When I push a media file (swf or png) to TFS, the process hangs at 100%, regardless of the file size:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" develop:develop

Counting objects: 82, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (23/23), 335.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 23 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: Are the deltas actually stored in the remote TFS? Are you running the above from the command line?

Comment: Corrected grammar a bit.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch

I tried to git bash, but process hans at 100%

I fetch it, But not store in the remote TFS

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this one. It seems that the push hangs if the commit contains a PNG file (as it was in my case). The response I got when sniffing the network was:

```
    401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
    You do not have permission to view this directory 
    or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

which is really beside the point; I can authenticate, clone and pull just fine.

Try this, it worked for me:

1. Reset the commit (`git reset HEAD~1` if it's the last commit). This is fine as long as you haven't pushed.
2. Add the files to the Git Index again, but without the PNG-file.
3. Commit.
4. Push.

The problem is in TFS and you need to involve its administrator.

Comment: I just downgraded to Git for Windows version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0 and it resolved the problem for me. After some substantial digging, it turns out that there is a problem with the HTTP(S) module in version 1.9.x in conjuction with authentication and HTTP chunked mode.